# Java, TextArea used to create SQL statement

Tags: java, sql, database

Im trying to make a program where I can type in a any sql statement in a textarea and then it will execute it. If it isnt a query then ill just show in a label the affected rows or if it was a query then show the results. I know how to fill a jtable with a resultset. But im a bit stuck the query vs nonquery part.

Comment: Do you mean something like if it's `insert` or `delete` command as compared to "select"?

Comment: Use the `execute` method of the `Statement` interface.  Its return value tells you whether there's a `ResultSet` to get.

Comment: im trying to build a mini plsql developer window as a project so thats why any sql sentence can be typed in

Comment: @DavidWallace dude you rock cant belive it was that simple, thx

Answer (score 1):

You may go with sth like:

```
package default;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;

    public class DBConnector {



        private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
        {
            String url       = "your-url";
            String user      = "user";
            String password  = "password";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            return conn;
        }

        public Vector<Vector<String>> ExecuteQuery(String query)
        {
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            //Vector of vectors for JTable
            Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
            try {
                //Create new statement
                stmt = getConnection().createStatement();
                //Execute given `query`
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


                if (stmt.execute(query)) {
                    rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                }

                //while there are some rows
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    //Create new Vector
                    Vector<String> temp = new Vector<String>();
                    int numColumns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                    //Put data into that vector
                    for ( int i = 1 ; i <= numColumns ; i++ ) {
                       temp.addElement(rs.getString(i));
                    }

                    //Add vector to `data`
                    data.add(temp);
                }

            }
            catch (SQLException ex){
                // handle any errors
                System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
                System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
                System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            }
            finally {
                if (rs != null) {
                    try {
                        rs.close();
                    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { }

                    rs = null;
                }

                if (stmt != null) {
                    try {
                        stmt.close();
                    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { } // ignore

                    stmt = null;
                }
            }
            //Return
            return data;
        }
    }
```

First you've got to fill `getConnection()` fields and then u may create JTable from calling `ExecuteQuery` passing `TextArea.getText()` String, cause you will get Vector of Vectors to pass to JTable.

Hope I helped :)